# Web App Active Directory User Roles vs User.IsInRole

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need a bit of advice.
I'm extending a web app to integrate with AD member roles, and not too sure whether i can rely on User.IsInRole to have the member role information.  Initial tests show me it does, but what is the difference between using this, and writing a class to return the user roles with DirectorySearcher/AccountManagement for example?

Is one solution better than the other?

It looks to me as though it achieves the same thing in this case.  Am i right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use active directory authorization `Users.IsInRole` checks if the user is member of the given group. It is not exactly the same as checking the groups that the user belongs to, because that only gives the *direct* memberships. `Users.IsInRole` also checks nested group membership. An example:

- `UserA` is a member of `GroupA`
- `GroupA` is a member of `GroupB`

Now if you check the direct memberships of `UserA` you will only get `GroupA`. But `Users.IsInRole` will indicate that `UserA` is a member of `GroupB` thanks to the nesting.

Comment: I see what you're saying... makes sense and a valid point, depending on my requirements i suppose.  Users.IsInRole

Comment: After a bit more investigation i am also looking at using PrinciplePermission and Demand to secure functionality of methods.  Thanks for the great information.

Comment: Using `PrinciplePermission` or `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` is the easiest way to control access. It is also completely independent of the underlying identity provider, so your code will work both with Windows accounts and e.g. an ASP.Net Membership provider.

Comment: Actually, with the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace ([read excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) to learn more about it), calling `UserPrincipal.GetGroups()` will **also** return any nested memberships of the user

Answer (score 0):

Just use Users.IsInRole.  Don't make things harder on yourself.  This is what it's for.

Comment: IsInRole doesn't deal with spaces in the role name.  i.e. "Test Group"